# HowTo "correctly" avoid clipping in GraphicsRow[{Labeled[Graphics[]]}]? Both images and labels

Tags: graphics, formatting, grid-layouts

Version:"12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"

This code

`GraphicsRow[{Labeled[Graphics[{Circle[]}],"A=B-\!\(\*FractionBox[\(C\), \(2\)]\)"], Labeled[Graphics[{Circle[]}],"A=B-\!\(\*FractionBox[\(C\), \(2\)]\)"]}]`

produces this output:

[image]

How do I prevent the obvious clipping?  I can pad the images with a white-on-white circle to hide that clipping, but I still have clipping in the labels.  Padding is "cheating".  There should be a way to correctly prevent this clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

gr = GraphicsRow[{Labeled[Graphics[{Circle[]}], 
    "A\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]B\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]\!\(\*FractionBox[\
\(C\), \(2\)]\)"], 
   Labeled[Graphics[{Circle[]}], 
    "A\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]B\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]\!\(\*FractionBox[\
\(C\), \(2\)]\)"]}]
```

[image]

The clipping does not occur. Compare your values for these options

```
AbsoluteOptions[gr, {ImageMargins, ImagePadding, PlotRange, PlotRangeClipping,
   PlotRangePadding}]

(* {ImageMargins -> 0., ImagePadding -> All, 
 PlotRange -> {{0., 1152.}, {-606.9, 0.}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {6., 5.}} *)
```

Perhaps one or more defaults have been changed.

**EDIT:** Using an older version I observe the problem

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

GraphicsRow[
 Labeled[Graphics[{Circle[]}], #] & /@ {
   "A\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]B\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]\!\(\*FractionBox[\(C\),\
 \(2\)]\)",
   "A\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]B\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]\!\(\*FractionBox[\(C\),\
 \(2\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

The easiest solution is to use Row instead of GraphicsRow

```
Row[Labeled[Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> Small], #] & /@ {
   "A\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]B\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]\!\(\*FractionBox[\(C\),\
 \(2\)]\)",
   "A\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]B\[ThinSpace]-\[ThinSpace]\!\(\*FractionBox[\(C\),\
 \(2\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your PlotRange is different from mine, but I can't seem to get it to change by explicitly putting your values in the function call.  My values are {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}.  Other than that, the options are identical.

Comment: Meh! Row works, but at the cost of graphics quality.  Maybe if I get a stimulus check, I can upgrade.  Rona don't wiped me out.