# GraphicsGrids crops the plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to use `GraphicsGrids` to combine some plots (generated with `ListPlot`). The problem I'm having, is that the plots are not shown completely. In particular, the somewhat wide `AxesLabel` (for the vertical axis) is cropped. This happens even when these plots appear in the 2$^\textrm{nd}$ column, with a large `Spacings`. So I'm wondering how to avoid this problem.

Here's a simple example of the problem:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Table[j, {j, 1, 30}], AxesLabel -> {j, 
log \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[\[Psi], j, l] | 
   Subsuperscript[\[Psi], j, l]\[RightAngleBracket]}];
plot2 = ListPlot[Table[-j, {j, 1, 30}], AxesLabel -> {j, 
log \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[\[Psi], j, l] | 
   Subsuperscript[\[Psi], j, l]\[RightAngleBracket]}];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
```

Here's the output I get:

[image]

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I did do a search, but didn't find the answer.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include a minimal working example that replicates your problem. You can copy code directly from your input cell and format it using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window.

Comment: Can you post an example? Something like this, `GraphicsGrid@
 ConstantArray[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 10}}], {3, 4}]`? An appropriate setting of size/range options, like `ImagePadding`, might help. Or not. I can't just keep guessing, though. (Generally, functions have been tested and work; when they don't, it's because of something specific you're doing. Show us what it is.)

Comment: I'm trying to paste in an example, but the sites complains about formatting, should be fixed soon hopefully

Comment: @eddyardonne is it acceptable if we rotate the label of the y-axis or do you want them as they are? I am talking for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfdDd.png)

Comment: @bmf I could live with that.

Comment: To avoid cluttering with unnecessary stuff, I will wait to see if the others have a more elegant solution and will get back if nobody writes anything

Comment: This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U22OQ.png -- but I don't see anything cropped. Does it look right to you?

Comment: @MichaelE2 For me, the l of log is cropped away on both plots, the image I get does not look like yours, which is what I was hoping for. I'm using version 12.1 on a mac. Should I upload an image? If so, how?

Comment: I am on v12.2.0 Win7-x64 and the l of log is cropped on both plots. A possible solution is `GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}}, Spacings -> 2]`

Comment: @eddyardonne Can you try to adjust the size? Like this`GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}}, ImageSize -> number]`. I got this output with [`ImageSize`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdKlN.png)

Comment: An image would make it easier for others to understand the issue, so yes. [As an aside, I'll suggest using `Row[{log , "\[ThickSpace]", \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[\[Psi], j, l] |  Subsuperscript[\[Psi], j, l]\[RightAngleBracket]}]` for the label. It probably won't fix the cropping, but your label has the form `Times[log,...]` and you're relying on `Times` to sort the factors in the order you want. It happens here, but it might not happen with a different label.]

Comment: Save your work first and try something and please let me know if it crashes Mma front end. In the original code try: `GraphicsGrid[{{Pane@plot1, Pane@plot2}}]`. Resize the plot a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I'll play around with them, and come back to tell if it worked (and how) or not.

Comment: @Syed GraphicsGrid[{{Pane@plot1, Pane@plot2}}] does the trick for me. I don't know how to highlight code in comments, sorry.

Comment: For me the the only trick it does is it crashes the front end. The way you highlight code is to put it between back ticks and if you have difficult to format characters, you use three back ticks on either side. This is the key right next to the `1` under the Esc key.

Comment: @Syed since `Pane` is problematic for you, out of curiosity can you try `ImageSize -> 1000` inside the `GraphicsGrid`? The rest of the code taken from the OP.

Comment: `ImageSize -> 1000` inside the `GraphicsGrid` crashed the front end.

Comment: @Syed that was unexpected. Thanks for letting me know anyway :)

Comment: @Syed I wrote my suggestions as an answer. Hoping to see yours as well :-)

Comment: See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229904/howto-correctly-avoid-clipping-in-graphicsrowlabeledgraphics-both-ima).

Comment: I ended up using a combination of `Pane` and `ImageSize`, despite the crashes I was experiencing. I submitted a bug report, and got the reply that this bug is fixed in 13.0.1

Answer (score 2):

There are some excellent suggestions in the comments. I am presenting mine and hoping for at least two more answers :-) .

```
$Version
```

> 12

---

- Using [`ImageSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) inside [`GraphicsGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html)

We have

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Table[j, {j, 1, 30}], 
   AxesLabel -> {j, 
     "log" \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l] | 
        Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l]\[RightAngleBracket]}, 
   RotateLabel -> True];
plot2 = ListPlot[Table[-j, {j, 1, 30}], 
   AxesLabel -> {j, 
     "log" \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l] | 
        Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l]\[RightAngleBracket]}];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

> [image: imagesize]

---

- Using [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) and [`ImageSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html)

We proceed as follows:

```
p1 = Labeled[
   ListPlot[Table[j, {j, 1, 30}], 
    ImageSize -> 
     Full], {"log" \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l] | 
       Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l]\[RightAngleBracket], "j"}, {Left, 
    Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True];
p2 = Labeled[
   ListPlot[Table[-j, {j, 1, 30}], 
    ImageSize -> 
     Full], {"log" \[LeftAngleBracket]Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l] | 
       Subsuperscript[ψ, j, l]\[RightAngleBracket], "j"}, {Left, 
    Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True];
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: labeled]